# C# Fluent NHibernate Overview Mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have three classes:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentOverview : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Document : DocumentOverview
{
    public byte[] Data{ get; set; }
}
```

In my application there is a tree and I want to load document names and list them there. Only when an TreeItem is selected I'm loading the Document entity to save traffic.

**I don't want to have redundant code in my mapping**, so my first attempt was like this:

```
public class DocumentOverviewMaps<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : DocumentOverview
{
    public DocumentOverviewMaps()
    {
        Table("Documents");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class DocumentMaps : DocumentOverviewMaps<Document>
{
    public DocumentMaps()
    {
        Map(x => x.Data).CustomType<BinaryBlobType>().Nullable();
    }
}
```

This does not work I always get the big Document entity even when loading overviews.

I found out that you can use SubclassMap<> but that doesn't work because it is for loading from different tables.

**Is there any way to make this run without redundant code?**

Comment: What about lazy loading the `Data` property?

Comment: I'm using a webservice and send the entities to the clients I don't know if lazy loading works there.
Also I would have to change alot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
public class DocumentBaseMap : ClassMap<T> where T : DocumentOverview
{
    public DocumentBaseMap()
    {
        Table("Documents");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class DocumentOverviewMap : DocumentBaseMap<DocumentOverview>
{
}

public class DocumentMap : DocumentBaseMap<Document>
{
    public DocumentMap() 
        : base()
    {
        Map(x => x.Data).CustomType<BinaryBlobType>().Nullable();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if the lack of the type parameter in your base class map is the reason why you only get the `Document` type? The empty `DocumentOverviewMap` class is a bit smelly. If it's the need for defined maps of the `Document` and `DocumentOverview` types that's the problem, then there's probably a better way to do this.

Comment: I would rate this 7 / 10 since you have an additional class. But it works so I will go for this solution, thanks.

Comment: Sure. I think there's probably a better way, but I cannot think of it right now.